# Accessing a file in a Java applet

Tags: java

I'm leaning Java language. And I am wondering how can I possible to access(read/write) a text file in a java applet that reside in a server?

Please advise.

Many thanks

EDIT:
Only read access but is there any method or way to implement that my app can save a data to a server, like database?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't write/update it but you can read its content using  `java.net.URL` and `java.net.URLConnection` classes.

Comment: So it's possible to update the content a text file. Only read access. Is there any way or method to implement that my applet will save a data to a server?

Comment: @krakat You can update the content of file which is located at server via "signed" applet or you can request to the server that causes the server to write to its own file system.

Comment: I think the signed applet is much more easier than the second one.